Pure Android NDK AIDL client
I want to build an Android NDK library (.so) which I use later on in Unity. In addition, I have an Android App which exposes a service based on AIDL.
Is it possible to implement the client for the AIDL service with NDK without using Java/Kotlin to bind the service?
I was able to generate the header/source files in C++ with "aidl" build tool. But all examples I found so far require Java code to send out the intent to bind the service.
